# create scrollable section in antd 4

Tags: css, reactjs, antd, scrollable

I need to create a list with inner scroll and a search input at the top in antd4 and react.
how can I create that like the image bellow?

scrollable section sketch example:

[image: scrollable section sketch example]

I couldn't find this component in [antd](https://ant.design/components/overview/) components.

Actually, I don't want to use the bellow code in css:

```
maxHeight: 200, overflow: 'auto'
```

Is there another solution without writing custom css codes? (I prefer to use antd components and features with less customization as much as possible)

Comment: This is not sth you can find in components, you should use different components. Input, List. some css and handle search by yourself.

Comment: I know. Actually my question was about inner scrolling. not the whole elements. I asked, Is there any antd component with inner scrolling? like section with inner scrolling. this component exist in other libraries like semantic-ui. But I couldn't fint it in antd. my question was that!

as I mentioned in the question, I know the css solution to create internal scroll. but I prefer to use original components if existed.

Comment: Its so easy, are you sure you want to handle it by components?

Comment: Nothing to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining a `height` and `overflow` should be sufficient for a scrolling antd list.

E.g.:

```
  overflow: auto;
  height: 300px;
```

Have a look at [this official antd list CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/h2vk3?file=/index.css:78-133) for a working code example.

Check the other examples for lists in the [antd List docs](https://ant.design/components/list/) too.

Comment: I've wrote this css solution in my question. So I didn't want it. I was looking for the example of antd components that used inner scrolling. The antd List Link that you gave me was helpful :) Thank you.

Comment: As a new user please have a look at at stackoverflows '[why vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)' too.